# swift 2.0: Detect whether a line has passed through specific point

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and ios. So far I have been able to draw a freeform line on UIImageView, now I want to know when the drawn line has passed\touched specific points on screen or not? How do we do this in swift 2.0 ?

Comment: This depends on how you're storing your line, and whether you want to be able to detect this as soon as it occurs (i.e. when a touch is close to the target), or after the fact (considering just the line and the point). It also depends a little on how precise you want this test to be. Is it exactly the intersection of the geometric (zero-width) line and the geometric (zero-size) point, or do you mean "the area covered by the drawn line overlaps the area near a point?"

Comment: It would be good if you can provide a code snippit on how should i do it. For reference consider following coordinates (100,150) (150,200) (350,50). So i want to know if a line has passed all of these coordinates +- 10 pixels.

Comment: How are you drawing the line? Can you provide some of your code? For example if you have the line in a format like y = mx + c you can calculate if it passes through the points very easily.

Comment: I actually wanted to know if the line has passed through an image. Something like connect the dots game. do you have any code sample for that ?